# What is the difference between web service and http and API?

Tags: http, web-services, backend

I am taking a course in web data so I understand that when we want to retrieve a web page on a browser we do a request response cycle using a communication protocol like http or https. A web service is a piece of software which I don't know where it is stored or how it is accessed. We can make two applications from different architectures communicate using  a serialization language like XML or JSON. I don't know what is the difference between a web service and http as they are both a way to connect two different computers together. What confused me the more is API which according to the research I did is something used to access web services.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with defining all the terms in your question since it's a bit all over the place.

**HTTP (Hypertext-Transport Protocol)**: Allows you to transfer data over the web. Your browser will perform a request using HTTP to your web service.

**Service**: Any software that performs a specific task. We are interested in a web service, which is typically invoked via HTTP, however this can be anything else such as a Linux signal.

For now, let's assume it listens on HTTP.

**API (Application Programming Interface)**: An interface by which all clients of your software have to abide by to use it. For example, in our web service, we can dictate an API so requests follow some convention.

Let's put it all together now.

---

You're making a website that wants to calculate the sum of two numbers. First, users will go to `http://yoursite.com`, and then the browser will always do an HTTP request to the domain `yoursite.com` on port 80. This will hit either your hosting site or some backend server.

Here you have the option if you're using something like GitHub pages to serve static content or you have some server (i.e., serverd) that will load a file and serve it.

So now the web-browser did an HTTP request and your webpage should load with an `index.html`. The user can now click on buttons, and everything looks good until they press `Calculate` -- what happens now?

We want to offload the computation to our backend. We perform an *HTTP* request to our backend server. We can define an API, that is in our case an endpoint, so that the HTTP request can hit it and it'll return the sum of the two numbers.

How do we return the result? We need to represent the data somehow, and this can be done through a body payload that is encoded as either JSON or XML. Again, this is a serialization format and can encode it in various different ways. JSON is nice because you can parse it easily with JavaScript on the client side.

Great -- so now we got an entire site and it works! Now we can do an HTTP request from our browser straight to the backend according to our setup endpoint and it should fulfill our request. Notice how now we're using the API from the backend server from within our site.

Other keywords you can may run into: CORS, AJAX, Apache Server; good luck!